# Trouble with If statements in While loops

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

The if section of this code does not run properly when combined with the for loop. The printf command is never executed regardless of weather the if statement is satisfied. I have tried implementing both while and for loops and no luck. The purpose is user input to an array of only numeric values.
Below is the problematic portion of my C code. I've been learning C for about a week so excuse my ignorance :).

```
int value;
int containsValues[5];
int x = 0;
int i = 0;

for (x<5;x++)
{
  printf("Enter value: \n");
  scanf("%d", &value);

  if  (isdigit(value))
   printf("A numeric value must be entered\n");
  else
   containsValues[x] = value;
}
```

Comment: This won't even compile as it stands - please post the *actual* code, not an approximation of it.

Comment: Does this compile `for (x<5;x++)`?

Comment: Check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns. That will tell you if a number was entered or not.

Comment: Besides that fact that it shouldn't compile because of the for not being correct syntax, shouldn't it be if(!isdigit(value)) instead?

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit(int c)` will return true if `c` is a numeric character (0-9) not if `c` is an `int`. For example `isdigit(48)` is true because the ASCII code 48 refers to digit `0`. But `isdigit(0)` will return false.

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit` takes an int, but `int(1)` is not `char('1')`.

If you want to test if you actually read an integer, use the result of [`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

```
int value;
int containsValues[5];
int i = 0;
for (int x = 0; x< 5;) {
  printf("Enter value: \n");
  if (1 != scanf("%d", &value)) { // scan return number of value read.
    printf("A numeric value must be entered\n");
  } else {
    containsValues[x] = value;
    x++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have the condition backwards; it needs to be true if the `scanf` does *not* find one number.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking to test if the value != 1 (well, in that case, scanf should return only 1 or 0).

Comment: Aside from the fact that it leaves the array undefined when the input is bad (as does the OP) this looks correct now.